# File Upload doesn't work in Mobile web view ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, media-queries

For my project, I have used the multiple file upload using this https://github.com/fyneworks/multifile#tab-Download

This worked perfectly fine in the web view.

In the web view, when I select a file, the file name will appear below the choose file button.

But when I open it in mobile view using the browser, I can select the file, but it won't add ed.

Also, I checked the controller as well, and there were also no files sent from the view even though I added some.

But working in the normal web view there is nothing error. working fine.

Can I know any reason this happening?

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="font-weight-bold" style="color:red">Please upload the task related all documents, if you have it now (Not Mandatory) <br />Maximum size for one document is 5 Mb </label>
  <input id="files" name="files" value="@Model.files" type="file" class="multi maxsize-5120" accept="jpg|pdf" multiple="multiple" />
</div>
```

When I do the inspect element, I found that in the normal web view, when I select a file, it creates `` and saved the file inside the tag.

But when I changed it to the mobile view, It doesn't create the span tag.

will this be the problem ??

This is the related javascript code from the script.

```
var names = $('<span/>');
$.each(files, function (i, file) {
  var v = String(file.name || '').replace(/[&<>'"]/g, function (c) {
      return '&#' + c.charCodeAt() + ';';
    }),
    S = MultiFile.STRING,
    n = S.label || S.file || S.name,
    t = S.title || S.tooltip || S.selected,
    p = file.type.substr(0, 6) == 'image/' ? '<img class="MultiFile-preview" style="' + MultiFile.previewCss + '"/>' : '',
    label = $(
      (
        '<span class="MultiFile-label" title="' + t + '">' +
        '<span class="MultiFile-title">' + n + '</span>' +
        (MultiFile.preview || $(slave).is('.with-preview') ? p : '') +
        '</span>'
      )
      .replace(/\$(file|name)/gi, (v.match(/[^\/\\]+$/gi) || [v])[0])
      .replace(/\$(ext|extension|type)/gi, (v.match(/[^\.]+$/gi) || [''])[0])
      .replace(/\$(size)/gi, sl(file.size || 0))
      .replace(/\$(preview)/gi, p)
      .replace(/\$(i)/gi, i)
    );

  // now supports preview via locale string.
  // just add an <img class='MultiFile-preview'/> anywhere within the "file" string
  label.find('img.MultiFile-preview').each(function () {
    var t = this;
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
      t.src = oFREvent.target.result;
    };
  });

  // append file label to list
  if (i > 0 && !!o.separator) names.append(o.separator);
  names.append(label);

  var v = String(file.name || '');
  names[names.length] =
    (
      '<span class="MultiFile-title" title="' + MultiFile.STRING.selected + '">' +
      MultiFile.STRING.file +
      '</span>'
    )
    .replace(/\$(file|name)/gi, (v.match(/[^\/\\]+$/gi) || [v])[0])
    .replace(/\$(ext|extension|type)/gi, (v.match(/[^\.]+$/gi) || [''])[0])
    .replace(/\$(size)/gi, sl(file.size || 0))
    .replace(/\$(i)/gi, i);
});
```

Can anyone have a solution for this? I'm not good at javascript. I couldn't find the issue.